# Octave: quadprog index issue?

Tags: optimization, octave, quadprog

I am trying to run several files of code for an assignment. I am trying to solve an optimization problem using the "quadprog" function from the "optim" package.

quadprog is supposed to solve the optimization problem in a [certain](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) format and takes inputs H,f, A,b, Aeq, Beq, lb, ub.

The issue I am having involves my f which is a column vector of constants. To clarify, f looks like c*[1,1,1,1,1,1] where c is a constant. Quadprog seems to run my code just fine for certain values of c, but gives me the error:

**error: index (_,49): but object has size 2x2**

**error: called from
    quadprog at line 351 column 32**

for other values of c. So, for example, 1/3 works, but 1/2 doesn't. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Sorry for not providing a working example. My code runs over several files and I seem to only be having problems with a specific value set that is very big. Thanks!

Comment: The title is misleading. This is Octave, not Matlab, right?

Comment: Correct: Sorry about this - I will update

Comment: Edit: Issue was resolved using Matlab! No idea why octave gave me problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [qp](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Quadratic-Programming.html) native Octave function.

You mention f is: c*[1,1,1,1,1,1]  but, if c is a scalar, that is not a column vector. It seems very odd that a scalar value might produce a dimensions error...